# Disable commands in Alpine Linux

Tags: security, symlink, command, busybox, alpine-linux

I want to attempt to increase the security of some Alpine Linux Docker containers which run Nginx and other servers.

I would like to disable commands like `ls`, `cat`, `ed` or `sed`, so that they are completely unavailable for users which manage to get access to a shell.

These commands should be available during Docker's build phase, it should be one last entry in the `Dockerfile` which removes these commands.

Would removing symlinks to `/bin/busybox` of the respective commands be enough? Could they somehow be recreated by a hacker?

Comment: If the users have `root`, which I'm assuming that they do in order to manage `nginx` and other servers, then there's nothing that you can do. Any restrictions that you could possibly put into place could simply be removed. Furthermore, there really isn't any sensible reason to remove commands like `ls`, `cat`, `ed`, and `sed` in this case as doing so would have no effect whatsoever on security.

Comment: This isn't really the right way to secure a Docker container. Many of these commands are necessary for the system inside to function. I'd start with this - https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/.

Comment: This is impossible since Alpine uses busybox, and by default ls, cat, ed and sed are applet of buysbox itself. If you /really/ want to do that, you should rebuild busybox by yourself and make a custom Alpine docker image using your own busybox.

Comment: This could give additional security. can anyone give a way to remove all commands that are not needed?